# Not able to create MD5 Hash on Cloudflare Worker Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudflare, serverless

I am trying to implement custom authorization of requests, before sending them to microservices, I am using Cloudflare worker scripts for the authorization and I am not able to generate the MD5 hash through worker script.

I have gone through many blogs and articles online but was not able to achieve the end result.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Mentioned below is the glimpse of what I am trying to do

```
 addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    importScripts('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/md5.js');
    let test = CryptoJS.MD5('test').toString();
    console.log(test);
    event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
```

Comment: Share what you have in `importScripts` ?

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/core.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/md5.js

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to import external libraries to calculate `md5` hash in Cloudflare Workers.

It's supported natively:

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

/**
 * Respond to the request
 * @param {Request} request
 */
async function handleRequest(request) {
  const message = "Hello world!"
  const msgUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode(message) // encode as (utf-8) Uint8Array
  const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('MD5', msgUint8) // hash the message
  const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)) // convert buffer to byte array
  const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('') // convert bytes to hex string

  return new Response(hashHex, {status: 200})
}
```

When triggered, it will respond with `86fb269d190d2c85f6e0468ceca42a20` which is `md5` of `Hello world!`.

Reference:

- https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/web-crypto
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks alot.

Comment: This same script can be used for other hashing algorithms. Cloudflare workers has a 50ms limit at the time of writing this comment, so this makes it challenging for using very strong algorithms. However, there are still algorithms available that work under the cap & self-hosted solutions that are infinitely better than using MD5. At this point in time, MD5 should not be used for anything because it's just marginally better than not hashing at all. It can be bruteforced w/ modern hardware quickly & easily. Please see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash

Answer (score 1):

here's an example of Cloudflare Workers hashing without a library, except using the SHA-256 algorithm in place of the obsolete MD5

```
export default {
  async fetch(request)
  {
    const myText = new TextEncoder().encode('Hello world!');
    const myDigest = await crypto.subtle.digest({ name: 'SHA-256' }, myText);
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(myDigest));
    const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')
    return new Response(hashHex, {status: 200});
  }
}
```