# Input from website link same as API in Cloudflare Worker

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am using Cloudflare worker scripts for generating the MD5 hash for extra security steps for user authorization in my server.

I have viewed the code from other StackOverflow question
([Not able to create MD5 Hash on Cloudflare Worker Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63397714/not-able-to-create-md5-hash-on-cloudflare-worker-script)):

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const message = "hi"
  const msgUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode(message) 
  const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('MD5', msgUint8) 
  const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)) 
  const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')

  return new Response(hashHex, {status: 200})
}
```

The input of the hash needs to be changed manually cause it is inside the code, declared in a variable. What I want that the code automatically gets the string from the link same as API, like if I access `https://example.example.workers.dev/&string=hi` or something related, it will get the string `hi`, then put it into the code, and after that get an MD5 hash `6152496c47126ba1079afd2a0b63645d`.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?